# Normal closure of a finite set

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I am studying a proof that states that in every finitely presented residually finite group $G=\langle X \mid R \rangle $ the word problem is solvable.

At some point it states that we can enumerate all words equal to $1$ in $G$ (that means we can enumerate all words for the normal closure of $R$ in $F(X)$.) Why is this possible?

The normal closure is the kernel of $\nu : F(X) \to G$ but I don't see why this should be finite.

Comment: “Enumerate” doesn’t mean finite. It means “listable” (the natural numbers are enumerable, but not finite).

Comment: I thought of that but the goal is to solve the word problem. If the normal closure isn't finite  how we will know in finite number of steps if g represents the identity?

Comment: You don’t need it to be finite to be decidable; if you have a list of nonnegative integers that is strictly increasing, even if the list is infinite you can still decide if a given number is on the list or not, and you can do so in a finite number of steps. So you are incorrect in assuming that it would be finite. In fact, the only subgroup of a free group that is finite is the trivial subgroup, let alone a normal subgroup.

Comment: Ok yes I see what you mean.. For some reason I first thought that in order to decide in finite steps we need finite set but I see now why this is not necessarily true. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly *isn't* finite! But it is *enumerable*. That is, possibly countable, but with the bonus property that some computer program can tell you if any given word is in the list.

For instance, the even natural numbers are enumerable, as witnessed by the following program

```
def isEven(n):
  return n % 2 == 0
```

Similarly, you can check if a given word is in the normal closure of $R$. How? Well every element of the normal closure is a finite product of conjugates of elements of $R$. We can enumerate all the elements of $G$ by looking at words in the generators $X$, and then we can enumerate all the conjugates of words in $R$ since there's finitely many, and then we can enumerate all the finitely many products of conjugates too.

You have to be a bit careful to make sure you actually hit everything, but it's doable with standard tricks. Here's the idea:

```
i = 0
while(true):
  ws = [all tuples of length <= i from R] # note there's finitely many
  gs = [all tuples of length <= i from X] # note there's finitely many
  for (r1,...,rn) in ws:
    for g1 ... gn in gs: 
      print(r1^g1 r2^g2 ... rn^gn)
  i += 1
```

The "residually finite" condition tells you how to check that a given element *doesn't* appear on this list. But I'm not entirely sure how right now.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: You need more than simply enumerable; you need it to be effective in some way that lets you tell if a given element not only has not yet appeared, but will *not* appear in the future.

Comment: woops - good catch. I'm so used to working with r.e. stuff I defaulted to that.